# Upload image and insert data to db issue

Tags: php, html

Trying to build this page for adding new products,for my client
Page with a form - 
1)To upload the image
2)Add price and name data

For some reason its not working. After i click on the submit button,nothing happens,its stayens on the saveimage.php page

```html
<form action="saveimage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<input name="name" type="text">שם:</br>

<input name="price" type="text">מחיר:</br>
 
<input name="category" value="<?php $category ?>" type="hidden">
 
<input name="uploadedimage" type="file">

<input name="new_product" type="submit" value="Upload Image">
 
</form>
```

The PHP page

```js
 <?php
include("../../dbconn.php");

    function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
     {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
       switch($imagetype)
       {
           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
           case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';
     case 'jpeg': return '.jpg';
     case 'PNG': return '.png';
     case 'JPG': return '.jpg';
           default: return false;
       }
     }
  
  
  
if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {

 $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
 $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
 $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
 $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
 $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
 $target_path = "img/".$imagename;
}

if(isset($_POST['new_product'])) {

    if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price'])) 
    {
 $product_name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
 $product_price = strip_tags($_POST['price']);
 $category = strip_tags($_POST['category']);
 }

if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {

  $query_upload="INSERT into products ('product_name','product_price','product_pic','category') VALUES ('".$product_name."', '".$product_price."', '".$image_name."', '".$category."')";


 mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error());  
 
}else{

   exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
} 
else{

   header('Location: upload_image_food.php?cname='.$category.');
    }
} 
?>;
```

Comment: I think you want to change `<input name="category" value="<?php $category ?>" type="hidden">` to `<input name="category" value="<?php echo $category; ?>" type="hidden">`. Without echo it does nothing..

Comment: thx for pointing that,still no luck with adding the pic&data

Answer (score 0):

Few changes.

**1)** Change

`<input name="category" value="<?php $category ?>" type="hidden">`

to

`<input name="category" value="<?php echo $category; ?>" type="hidden">`

**2)** Change (Remove single quotes `'` around column name)

```
$query_upload="INSERT into products ('product_name','product_price','product_pic','category') VALUES ('".$product_name."', '".$product_price."', '".$image_name."', '".$category."')";
```

To

```
$query_upload = "INSERT into products (product_name,product_price,product_pic,category) VALUES ('$product_name', '$product_price', '$image_name','$category')";
```

**3)** Add `header("Location: upload_image_food.php?cname=$category&Message=Success");` inside `move_uploaded_file` because when it is success then, it need to go to desired location with some message. This is the reason why it's showing blank.

**4)**
Change

```
}else{

   exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
} 
else{

   header('Location: upload_image_food.php?cname='.$category.');
    }
} 
?>;
```

to

```
}else{

         exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
    }
}
else{
    header("Location: upload_image_food.php?cname=$category");
}
?>
```

**Somepage.php**

```
<form action="saveimage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input name="name" type="text">שם:</br>
    <input name="price" type="text">מחיר:</br>
    <input name="category" value="<?php echo $category ?>" type="hidden">
    <input name="uploadedimage" type="file">
    <input name="new_product" type="submit" value="Upload Image">
</form>
```

**saveimage.php**

```
function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
{
    if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
    switch($imagetype)
    {
         case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
         case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
         case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
         case 'image/png': return '.png';
         case 'jpeg': return '.jpg';
         case 'PNG': return '.png';
         case 'JPG': return '.jpg';
         default: return false;
    }
}



if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {

    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
    $target_path = "img/".$imagename;
}

if(isset($_POST['new_product'])) 
{

  if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price'])) 
  {
        $product_name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
        $product_price = strip_tags($_POST['price']);
        $category = strip_tags($_POST['category']);
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) 
    {

        $query_upload = "INSERT into products (product_name,product_price,product_pic,category) VALUES ('$product_name', '$product_price', '$image_name','$category')";

        mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error());  
        header("Location: upload_image_food.php?cname=$category&Message=Success");
    }
    else
    {
         exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
    } 
else
{
        header("Location: upload_image_food.php?cname=$category");
}
?>
```

Comment: Please copy my whole code now. Don't do a single change. Blindly copy both code. And work @Mike. I have done lot of changes now.

Comment: Then there might some different issue regarding .htaccess file. But, these changes are mandatory for you to change. @Mike

Comment: I wrote $imagename in $_FILES and  $image_name in ther INSERT query,but thats not the problem either